# cargar un contenido dinamico desde un objeto del menu

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Buenas necesito saber como haciendo click en los diferentes objetos de las solapas del menu, me cargue diferente información. busqueda.php armaré un mysqli_query para obtener la tabla que cumplen con la condicion y desplegarlo, pero necesito saber como crear la variable (lo intenté de diferentes formas sin éxito) o bien tener una url dinamica pero queria evitar cargar toda la web y solo el div que oculto/muestro
    


    Estilo MT

```
function myFunction1() {
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}};
function myFunction2() {
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}};
function myFunction3() {
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV3");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}};
function myFunction4() {

var x = document.getElementById("front");
var y = document.getElementById("busc");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.style.display = "none"
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "block";

}};
```

```
<!--ENCABEZADO-->
<div class="contentLogo">
    <div class="header-col-izq">
        <div class="buscador"> BUSCADOR </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-col-cen">
        <img class="logoPrincipal" src="img/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="header-col-der">
        <div class="redes">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/MT.Estilo/">
                <img class="btnRedes" alt="FB" onmouseout="this.src='img/fbblanco.png';" onmouseover="this.src='img/fbnegro.png';" >
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/estilo_mt/">
                <img class="btnRedes" alt="instagram" onmouseout="this.src='img/instablanco.png';" onmouseover="this.src='img/instanegro.png';" >
            </a>
            <a href="#" onclick="myFunction1()">
                <img class="btnRedes" alt="Contacto" onmouseout="this.src='img/ctcblanco.png';" onmouseover="this.src='img/ctcnegro.png';" >
            </a>
            <a href="#" onclick="myFunction2()">
                <img class="btnRedes" alt="Pagos" onmouseout="this.src='img/pagoblanco.png';" onmouseover="this.src='img/pagonegro.png';" >
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ventanaCtc" id="myDIV1" style="display: none;">
    <p>TEL: 4442-8026 / 8447</p>
    <p>WhatsApp: 15-6980-0529 </p>
    <p>Mail: estilo.mt@hotmail.com</p>
    <p>Boulogne Sur Mer 1334, Villa Madero</p>
</div>
<div class="ventanaCtc" id="myDIV2" style="display: none;">
    <p>TEL: 4442-8026 / 8447</p>
    <p>WhatsApp: 15-6980-0529 </p>
    <p>Mail: estilo.mt@hotmail.com</p>
    <p>Boulogne Sur Mer 1334, Villa Madero</p>
</div>

<div class="linea"></div>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        <li>MUJER
            <ul>
                <li onclick="myFunction4()" name="variable"><a>Carteras</a></li>
                <li onclick="myFunction4()" name="variable"><a href="#">Mochilas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bandoleras</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Carteras de Fiesta</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bolsos MAternales</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sport</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Billeteras</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Otros</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>HOMBRE
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Porta Notebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mochilas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Morrales</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Maletines</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Billeteras</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Otros</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>NIÑOS
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Mochilas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cartucheras</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Libreria</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Luncheras</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Otros</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>ACCESORIOS
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Cintos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Paraguas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chalinas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Porta Cosméticos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Otros</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>EQUIPAJE
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Valijas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bolsos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Accesorios</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>REGALERIA
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Mates</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bazar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Vinos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cuchillería</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tablas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Librería</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">E.e.</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Otros</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Promociones</a></li>
    </ul>
<br>
<div id="front">
<?php
include_once 'prodFront.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);


?>
```

```
            <!-- normal -->
            <div class="ih-item circle effect3 left_to_right"><a href="#" onclick="myFunction3()">
                <div class="img"><img src="<?php echo "img/upload/".$row1[foto];?>" alt="img"></div>
                <div class="info">
                  <h3><?php echo $row1[titulo]; ?></h3>
                  <p style="margin-right: 25%;"><?php echo $row1[info]; ?></p>
                  <p>Precio: <?php echo $row1[precio]; ?></p>
                  <p>Marca <?php echo $row1[marca]; ?></p>
                  <button class="btnPedir">Pedir Ahora!</button>
                </div></a></div>
            <!-- end normal -->

          </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="celda">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">

            <!-- normal -->
            <div class="ih-item circle effect3 left_to_right"><a href="#" onclick="myFunction3()">
                <div class="img"><img src="<?php echo "img/upload/".$row2[foto];?>" alt="img"></div>
                <div class="info">
                  <h3><?php echo $row2[titulo]; ?></h3>
                  <p style="margin-right: 25%;"><?php echo $row2[info]; ?></p>
                  <p>Precio: <?php echo $row2[precio]; ?></p>
                  <p>Marca <?php echo $row2[marca]; ?></p>
                  <button class="btnPedir">Pedir Ahora!</button>
                </div></a></div>
            <!-- end normal -->

          </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="celda">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">

            <!-- normal -->
            <div class="ih-item circle effect3 left_to_right"><a href="#" onclick="myFunction3()">
                <div class="img"><img src="<?php echo "img/upload/".$row3[foto];?>" alt="img"></div>
                <div class="info">
                  <h3><?php echo $row3[titulo]; ?></h3>
                  <p style="margin-right: 25%;"><?php echo $row3[info]; ?></p>
                  <p>Precio: <?php echo $row3[precio]; ?></p>
                  <p>Marca <?php echo $row3[marca]; ?></p>
                  <button class="btnPedir">Pedir Ahora!</button>
                </div></a></div>
            <!-- end normal -->

          </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="celda">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">

            <!-- normal -->
            <div class="ih-item circle effect3 left_to_right"><a href="#" onclick="myFunction3()">
                <div class="img"><img src="<?php echo "img/upload/".$row4[foto];?>" alt="img"></div>
                <div class="info">
                  <h3><?php echo $row4[titulo]; ?></h3>
                  <p style="margin-right: 25%;"><?php echo $row4[info]; ?></p>
                  <p>Precio: <?php echo $row4[precio]; ?></p>
                  <p>Marca <?php echo $row4[marca]; ?></p>
                  <button class="btnPedir">Pedir Ahora!</button>
                </div></a></div>
            <!-- end normal -->

          </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="celda">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">

            <!-- normal -->
            <div class="ih-item circle effect3 left_to_right"><a href="#" onclick="myFunction3()">
                <div class="img"><img src="<?php echo "img/upload/".$row5[foto];?>" alt="img"></div>
                <div class="info">
                  <h3><?php echo $row5[titulo]; ?></h3>
                  <p style="margin-right: 25%;"><?php echo $row5[info]; ?></p>
                  <p>Precio: <?php echo $row5[precio]; ?></p>
                  <p>Marca <?php echo $row5[marca]; ?></p>
                  <button class="btnPedir">Pedir Ahora!</button>
                </div></a></div>
            <!-- end normal -->

          </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="celda">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">

            <!-- normal -->
            <div class="ih-item circle effect3 left_to_right"><a href="#" onclick="myFunction3()">
                <div class="img"><img src="<?php echo "img/upload/".$row6[foto];?>" alt="img"></div>
                <div class="info">
                  <h3><?php echo $row6[titulo]; ?></h3>
                  <p style="margin-right: 25%;"><?php echo $row6[info]; ?></p>
                  <p>Precio: <?php echo $row6[precio]; ?></p>
                  <p>Marca <?php echo $row6[marca]; ?></p>
                  <button class="btnPedir">Pedir Ahora!</button>
                </div></a></div>
            <!-- end normal -->

          </div>
        </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="busc" style="display: none;">
<?php 
include_once 'tmp/busqueda.php' ?>
</div>
<div class="ventanaPedir" id="myDIV3" style="display: none;">
    <div class="cerrarX"><button onclick="myFunction3()" name="close">X</button></div>
    <div class="form-pedir">
        <form action="tmp/pedirProd.php" method="post">
            <label>Mi Nombre es:  </label><input type="text" name="nombre"><br><br>
            <label>Me pueden contactar al Teléfono (WhatspApp):  <br></label><input type="tel" name="telefono"><br><br>
            <label>Quiero Pedir...</label><br><input type="text" name="producto" value="Datos del producto" style="width: 100%;"><br><br>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Pedir</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sebas, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, para realizar respuestas [answer], saludos!

Answer (score -1):

Ya lo resolví con AJAX. Si alguno lo desea le comparto el código total.

Comment: sí, sería bueno que le dieras a [edit] para añadir el código de lo que usaste